# How can I forward an entire email thread (a.k.a. conversation) in Microsoft Outlook web interface?

Tags: outlook.com

How can I forward an entire email thread (a.k.a. conversation) in Microsoft Outlook web interface?

E.g., in Gmail one can do:

[image]